# Odoo9: ProgrammingError: relation "account_invoice_report" does not exist

Tags: odoo-9

While trying to open one of contacts in odoo9 it crashes, throwing following error:

```
2018-07-12 19:28:04,856 14098 INFO grp-hhrr openerp.sql_db: Programming error: relation "account_invoice_report" does not exist
LÍNEA 3:                     FROM account_invoice_report account_invo...
                                  ^
, in query 
                  SELECT SUM(price_total) as total, partner_id
                    FROM account_invoice_report account_invoice_report
                   WHERE (((("account_invoice_report"."partner_id" in (%s,%s))  AND  (("account_invoice_report"."state" not in (%s,%s)) OR "account_invoice_report"."state" IS NULL))  AND  ("account_invoice_report"."company_id" = %s))  AND  ("account_invoice_report"."type" in (%s,%s)))
                   GROUP BY partner_id

2018-07-12 19:28:04,856 14098 ERROR grp-hhrr openerp.http: Exception during JSON request handling.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/http.py", line 650, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/http.py", line 687, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/http.py", line 323, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/http.py", line 316, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/http.py", line 966, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/http.py", line 516, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 895, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 887, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/models.py", line 3208, in read
    result = BaseModel.read(records, fields, load=load)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/models.py", line 3254, in read
    values[name] = field.convert_to_read(record[name], use_name_get)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/models.py", line 5769, in __getitem__
    return self._fields[key].__get__(self, type(self))
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/fields.py", line 831, in __get__
    self.determine_value(record)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/fields.py", line 940, in determine_value
    self.compute_value(recs)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/fields.py", line 895, in compute_value
    self._compute_value(records)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/fields.py", line 885, in _compute_value
    getattr(records, self.compute)()
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/addons/account/models/partner.py", line 322, in _invoice_total
    self.env.cr.execute(query, where_clause_params)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/sql_db.py", line 154, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrador/Escritorio/GRP-HHRR/odoo9-GRP/openerp/sql_db.py", line 233, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
ProgrammingError: relation "account_invoice_report" does not exist
LÍNEA 3:                     FROM account_invoice_report account_invo...
                                  ^
```

I've already tried to update the module several times, and all of it's dependencies. I've also tried unsuccessfully to locate the file throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted my local git projects and pulled from master (which works), but error keeps going so it would seem it is a DataBase problem.

By deleting database and restoring a previous backup it all worked! So, please, do backup your db often.